# javascript error in Mobile Adapter in sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am developing a very simple web part mobile adpater. It just outputs "hello world". The mobile web part renders fine, but when i click on arrow image next to the Web part title , it throws javascript error "object expected" on "ExpandCollapse" function. I am viewing the page, by adding "?mobile=1" in my pc browser. I m using IE8. Please help.

When I looked at the HTML source of the rendered page, I noticed, the above errror is caused because  javascript function ExpandCollapse was not rendered.

Below is the HTML source

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="ctl00" name="ctl00" method="post" action="mblwp.aspx?__ufps=303904&Url=%2fPages%2fper.aspx&amp;mobile=1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEXAQULY3RsMDIkY3RsMDcUKwACZWQ0DWekHDAtSoDK+DzThd4XW94rSg==">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__V_ctl00_LastPage" value="1">
<script language=javascript><!--
function __doPostBack(target, argument){
 var theform = document.ctl00
 theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = target
 theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = argument
 theform.submit()
}
// -->
</script>

                <div style="color:White;background-color:#21374C;font-size:13pt;font-weight:bold;padding-right:6px;padding-left:6px;padding-bottom:12px;padding-top:12px;">



        Pages: per<br>




</div> <br>

            <div id="g_db56af97_19b2_40a6_a44a_aa5f6f61fb29__Summary" style="color:Black;font-size:Medium;">
    <a href="javascript:ExpandCollapse(g_db56af97_19b2_40a6_a44a_aa5f6f61fb29__Summary);javascript:ExpandCollapse(g_db56af97_19b2_40a6_a44a_aa5f6f61fb29__Detail)"><img src="/_layouts/images/mblwpsummarytitle.gif" border="0" /></a><b>PersonnelSearchWebPart
</b><br>
</div><div id="g_db56af97_19b2_40a6_a44a_aa5f6f61fb29__Detail" style="color:Black;font-size:Medium;display:none;">
    <a href="javascript:ExpandCollapse(g_db56af97_19b2_40a6_a44a_aa5f6f61fb29__Summary);javascript:ExpandCollapse(g_db56af97_19b2_40a6_a44a_aa5f6f61fb29__Detail)"><img src="/_layouts/images/mblwpdetailtitle.gif" border="0" /></a><b>PersonnelSearchWebPart</b><br>
    Hello World. This is the Mobile Device version of the SharePoint web part.
<br>
</div>


    &nbsp;<div style="background-color:#F6F6F6;padding-right:6px;padding-left:6px;padding-bottom:12px;padding-top:12px;">








                        <hr width="100%" size="1" color="#FFFFFF" align="center">
                        <div>

    </div>






        <a href="http://devcollab:286/_layouts/mobile/mbllists.aspx">All Site Content</a><br>


        <a href="http://devcollab:286/_layouts/mobile/mobilesearch.aspx">Search</a><br>

        <a href="http://devcollab:286/?Mobile=1">Home(Home)</a><br>


        <!-- place SSL VPN logout link here -->





</div>
            </form></body></html>
```